# Bake me a slice of cake

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

My birthday is in a month, and this is a slice of tasty cake.

```
    .-""-.
 .-"      "-.
|""--..      "-.
|      ""--..   "-.
|""--..      ""--..\
|      ""--..      |
|            ""--..|
 ""--..            |
       ""--..      |
             ""--..|
```

In the fewest number of bytes, construct this slice of cake for me. You can print it to STDOUT or return it as a function result.

Any amount of extraneous whitespace is acceptable, so long as the characters line up appropriately.

#### Rules and I/O

- No input
- Output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: How does one bake only a slice of cake? It would just be the entire cake at that point, no? `Cake[:]` need not apply.

Comment: @Veskah the Internet is ahead of you! (isn't it always)... https://www.dhgate.com/product/creative-diy-8-cavity-silicone-mold-pastry/415336422.html.

Comment: But... it is a lie, isn't it?

Answer (score 13):

## Eggsembly - 203 bytes

```
push '    .-""-.\n .-"      "-.\n|""--..      "-.\n|      ""--..   "-.\n|""--..      ""--..|\n|      ""--..      |\n|            ""--..|\n ""--..            |\n       ""--..      |\n             ""--..|'
```

Here is a less golfed version.

```
push '    .-""-.\n'
push ' .-"      "-.\n'
add
push '|""--..      "-.\n'
add
push '|      ""--..   "-.\n'
add
push '|""--..      ""--..\\n'
add
push '|      ""--..      |\n'
add
push '|            ""--..|\n'
add
push ' ""--..            |\n'
add
push '       ""--..      |\n'
add
push '             ""--..|\n'
add
```

---

This one works a bit differently, but it's significantly shorter in Chicken at 57,878 bytes.

```
push " "
push 4
rooster
push '.-""-.\n'
add
push ' .-"'
push " "
push 6
rooster
add
push '"-.\n'
add
push '|""--..'
push " "
push 6
rooster
add
push '"-.\n|'
add
push " "
push 6
rooster
add
push '""--..   "-.\n'
add
push '|""--..'
push " "
push 6
rooster
add
push '""--..\\n'
add
push '|'
push " "
push 6
rooster
add
push '""--..      |\n'
add
push '|'
push " "
push 12
rooster
add
push '""--..|\n'
add
push ' ""--..'
push " "
push 12
rooster
add
push '|\n'
add
push " "
push 7
rooster
add
push '""--..'
push " "
push 6
rooster
add
push '|\n'
add
push " "
push 13
rooster
add
push '""--..|\n'
add
add
add
add
add
add
add
add
```

---

## Chicken - <s>57,878</s> 28,135 bytes

```
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken

chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken
chicken chicken
```

So what was changed here is a little more understandable, here's the Eggsembly version.

```
push " "
push 4
rooster
push 4
peck
pick 4
axe
push '.-""-.\n'
add
push ' .-"'
pick 4
axe
push " "
push 2
rooster
add
push 6
peck
pick 6
axe
add
push '"-.\n'
add
push '|'
push '""--..'
push 2
peck
pick 2
axe
add
add
pick 6
axe
add
push '"-.\n'
add
push '|'
add
pick 6
axe
add
pick 2
axe
add
push " "
push 3
rooster
add
push '"-.\n'
add
push '|'
add
pick 2
axe
add
pick 6
axe
add
pick 2
axe
add
push '\\n'
add
push '|'
add
pick 6
axe
add
pick 2
axe
add
pick 6
axe
add
push '|\n'
add
push '|'
add
pick 6
axe
pick 6
axe
add
push 3
peck
pick 3
axe
add
pick 2
axe
add
push '|\n'
add
push " "
add
pick 2
axe
add
pick 3
axe
add
push '|\n'
add
pick 6
axe
push " "
add
add
pick 2
axe
add
pick 6
axe
add
push '|\n'
add
pick 3
axe
add
push " "
add
pick 2
axe
add
push '|\n'
add
add
```

Comment: See also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yL_-1d9OSdk).

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES8), <s>115</s> 112 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @ovs*

```javascript
_=>`4.-""-.
1.-"6"-.
|06"-.
|603"-.
|060\\
|606|
|660|
1066|
706|
670|`.replace(/\d/g,n=>''.padEnd(n)||'""--..')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BCsMgFET3OUY2KtSfH1p@VmbXWwiNqAktopKUrry7NbSbefNmMy/zMYfdn/ktY3K@rqo@1LzcQPa9hG5spLMU/IHw@lfU@lQqLQlLNyK1Pp0DTVgW2H0Oxno@aDdsl6hmxiAbd4@OR1EKawcSgIlqUzxS8BDSxlcuRP0C)

Answer (score 6):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>77</s> <s>65</s> <s>58</s> <s>54</s> <s>44</s> <s>43</s> <s>42</s> <s>40</s> 39 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
"-.＊＼＼＼
２⁸±４⁸＋３⁸２１＊⌐∔１３╋５|＊×ω\；∔Ａ«３╋０３╋
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JTIyLS4ldUZGMEEldUZGM0MldUZGM0MldUZGM0MlMEEldUZGMTIldTIwNzglQjEldUZGMTQldTIwNzgldUZGMEIldUZGMTMldTIwNzgldUZGMTIldUZGMTEldUZGMEEldTIzMTAldTIyMTQldUZGMTEldUZGMTMldTI1NEIldUZGMTUlN0MldUZGMEElRDcldTAzQzklNUMldUZGMUIldTIyMTQldUZGMjElQUIldUZGMTMldTI1NEIldUZGMTAldUZGMTMldTI1NEI_,v=8)

Explanation:

```
"-.*\\\  Helper function F taking an argument n
"-.*     an array of n strings `"-.`
    \\\  pad each line with 1 more space than the previous, 3 times
Main program:
2⁸                          execute F with 2
  ±                         reverse that
   4⁸+                      and append F(4) - the top of the cake

3⁸                          F(3)
  21*                       extend horizontally 2x and vertically 1x - create one stripe
     ⌐                      create extra 2 copies of that on the stack
      ∔                     append 2 of those together
       13╋                  and insert it at (1; 3) in the last line
          5|*               array of 5 "|"
             ×              prepend that to the left of the stripes
              ω             retrieve back the array of "|"
               \；∔         prepend "\" to that
                   A«3╋     and insert that at ((10<<1); 3) in the object
                       03╋  and join the two parts together
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
Ｆ³«↑Ｆι⸿↑Ｆ³¶""--..»↑⁵←\Ｆ⁴←¶.-"Ｆ²«←"-.↓»↓⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw1hToZqL0ze/LFXDKrRA05qLEyycqakQUJSZV6KhFFOkBBLFUGGMUJEXoxSjpKurpwdSWcsFEQaq1VEwBQpAuT6paSU6CkoxMSBFYBNMYCbA5fL0dGOU4PJGYKehKVHS1UNyj0t@eR6ynSA@2Nb////rluUAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ³«
```

Loop over the three horizontal lines.

```
↑Ｆι⸿↑
```

The lines overlap by an amount depending on which line we're on. This calculates the correct amount of overlap but also moves the cursor to the left of the canvas again.

```
Ｆ³¶""--..»
```

Repeat three times, move the cursor down one line and then print a third of the horizontal line.

```
↑⁵←\
```

Print the vertical line on the right and the backslash on the corner.

```
Ｆ⁴←¶.-"
```

Repeat four times, move the cursor up one line and then print a quarter of the diagonal.

```
Ｆ²«←"-.↓»
```

Print the other diagonal. (I couldn't find a way of combining the printing with the movement but this is still 2 bytes shorter than the next best way I could find.)

```
↓⁵
```

Print the vertical line on the left.

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL, <s>125</s> 121 bytes

```sql
PRINT REPLACE(REPLACE('    .-""-.
 .-"1"-.
|21"-.
|12   "-.
|212\ 
|121|
|112|
 211|
 121|
 112|',2,'""--..'),1,'      ')
```

Due to the overhead of the `REPLACE()` keyword, just two replacements gave me the best score. SQL allows line breaks inside of strings, so I don't have to replace those with `CHAR(13)` or whatever.

Hard to tell in the code above, but I had to add an extra space after the `\`, because normally that would be an escape character that would cause it to ignore the subsequent line break.

**EDIT**: Saved 4 bytes by changing my replacement characters to numerals instead of letters. This lets me eliminate the single quotes since `REPLACE` casts them to strings implicitly.

This generates:

```
    .-""-.
 .-"      "-.
|""--..      "-.
|      ""--..   "-.
|""--..      ""--..\ 
|      ""--..      |
|            ""--..|
 ""--..            |
       ""--..      |
             ""--..|
```

Happy birthday (next month)!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 99 bytes

```bash
00000000: 2363 6f64 696e 673a 4c31 0a70 7269 6e74  #coding:L1.print
00000010: 2278 da53 5050 50d0 d355 52d2 d5e3 02d1  "x.SPPP..UR.....
00000020: 5c6e 605c 30e2 d55c 30c5 74f5 f490 04a0  \n`\0..\0.t.....
00000030: 4c98 30a6 5c22 303b 0643 2110 d4c0 0491  L.0.\"0;.C!.....
00000040: a56a b850 d4c0 542a 60d3 ae80 453b 5c30  .j.P..T*`...E;\0
00000050: a94e 1d27 222e 6465 636f 6465 2827 7a69  .N.'".decode('zi
00000060: 7027 29                                  p')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZE/T8MwEMV3PsWjDAGkWhfbZydtN@hWVRV/tgx1Y4eWIa1Kh4L47uFCM7Bxkq2TfO93786b8LHtzueI8RGzWTZfPmb4xuHztN23GuOOhphAG2fgGmfhSpfgvAmwtclBwRO8diVc8ha4qfdx175NFrk6HHft6epCyHuG9gViYAMmJrkiIRpmsI4akZMB6ZgDo7N6Xq1WSr0@qT4GhhYG13134hqGUi/6zWqGtw2jsSWBbCCgatcVKSXn9JdhhGHrshBRcELTWjKzATlroPNcHNm6Z5TiY6FIVSOaqofrvwwrjMAuYFPwUM9WB7EVDUIqCJYFybURH@pdySAv92vRz6cVDQzuGaVNyKP2shktU1nHcMY1l0wX8uCDLBZqqbKRiklWm26zr93AcMLw1Mul5r84ZHed/G/3Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 47+61=108 bytes

Once again stolen from @DigEmAll's nice answer previously, just compress to gzip and decompress in a 2 part answer.

```r
cat(memDecompress(readBin('a','raw',61),'g',T))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7BasMwDL37K4QpKA6OYTvsMOil2yf0mIvaqJuhcYLtUDry75mSNdDRCoOlp/eeXpxoiyDlKq0rp@YflpqnUbDKuTvg1q7wI2np6wei1LiC96tR/eOsTHgmhydyVOoSfeadD0XL7UfX9pFTKshYJDRKHSkXuixL2H/7BPIIXuHkzwxpOLQ@Jd8FJ0sGahqfZaIzHK6ZEzQDQ@7Ah37If5JALTcgxkCR4R20XXDnw6krNGmzSf6HLeDNQe6ixTrUAW3ifqu1meZAkvSTj2vWyNTM@cXXYqQL2rcXif@Fdm/MNP0C)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 58 bytes

```
”. -"|\
”S”""--..”ð6×)˜•I8Γ·³§€ΓÎíÈÜ7γ¿·U₃´îØ©G¹râî.
d•SèJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWsAlP9vc2FiaWX//@KAnS4gLSJ8XArigJ1T4oCdIiItLS4u4oCdw7A2w5cpy5zigKJJOM6TwrfCs8Kn4oKszpPDjsOtw4jDnDfOs8K/wrdV4oKDwrTDrsOYwqlHwrlyw6LDri4KZOKAolPDqEr//w)

Comment: After seeing the other answers I knew a more algorithmic built-up would be shorter. :) Too bad `•2ā_/¦Y ¸|pζÚˆ#ñÕηbp^Ωÿ_veCuŽJ•9в` is the same amount of bytes as `•I8Γ·³§€ΓÎíÈÜ7γ¿·U₃´îØ©G¹râî.\nd•S`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: I wanted to try using the canvas, but I feel like due to the multi-string "elements" it will likely be longer.

Comment: Hmm, in my experience canvas is usually longer for such complex strings. I would still be interested to see an answer using canvas as comparison, but I seriously doubt it will be near your current byte-count.

Answer (score 2):

## Twig, 126 bytes

This is just a simple search/replace.
Nothing fancy

```
{{'012
 10  2430  240  3   2430  3\\40  30  |40003|
 3000|
0   30  |
000 3|'|replace(['    ','.-"','"-.','""--..','
|'])|raw}}
```

Try this on https://twigfiddle.com/8zxyxa

Under "Result", click in "Show raw result", or else you will see this:

```
        .-""-.
    .-"      "-.
|""--..      "-.
|      ""--..   "-.
|""--..      ""--..\
|      ""--..      |
|            ""--..|
    ""--..            |
            ""--..      |
                ""--..|
```

Which looks closer to melting cheese than a cake slice...

---

Sadly, your cake has to be `|raw`, or you would get this:

```
        .-&quot;&quot;-.
    .-&quot;      &quot;-.
|&quot;&quot;--..      &quot;-.
|      &quot;&quot;--..   &quot;-.
|&quot;&quot;--..      &quot;&quot;--..\
|      &quot;&quot;--..      |
|            &quot;&quot;--..|
    &quot;&quot;--..            |
            &quot;&quot;--..      |
                &quot;&quot;--..|
```

Which looks like .... I don't know :x

Comment: but OP specifically asked for a baked slice D:

Comment: :x Sorry, must be `|raw` to work

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 116 bytes

```python
print('''    .-" .-"||   |\\
||
||
 |
 |
 |'''.translate({1:'""--..',2:' '*6,3:'"-.\n'}))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtNCoMwEIWZcecpQjajJRmwggvPkk0WBYWSimZTmp49vgy8vw/m@Obtk@Zaj3NPeRARg1Nvu2bcFYKYwFqlEHosLnCm0htidDaNMKLgX/MZ0/WO@TX8plWs9V5V3HMVI4/FzUBeQ5L/ONZ6Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>158</s> 125 bytes

```python
print"""    .-""-.
 .-"s"-.
|es"-.
|se   "-.
|ese\\
|ses|
|sse|
 ess|
 ses|
 sse|""".replace('e','""--..').replace('s',' '*6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcwxCoAwDAXQ3VOELFGxGRw8jYtIQEFqaboIvXtNVTBD8nmBH660nX4sJcTdJ0QEG3aIjpt6tYYs71Gx5wcyzxU021bJDYhahkeginVxlHAsq7QkNJB1OmbqflVToH7qSrkB)

---

Basically a translation of the JS and T-SQL answers

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>84</s> <s>82</s> 81 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
“
 "-.\|“•6ÅΩæÍ[ÕŽÇ4Δ¼µðв‹ìbÿ¹0mĆÛh6Ë\HvçÏ—ÜâE«εx±5Â\₅δćzÁ₅3¨Éj€¾ï737Æüí·?т¹•7вèJ
```

-3 bytes thanks to *@Emigna*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AZYAaf9vc2FiaWX//@KAnAogIi0uXHzigJzigKI2w4XOqcOmw41bw5XFvcOHNM6UwrzCtcOw0LLigLnDrGLDv8K5MG3EhsObaDbDi1xIdsOnw4/igJTDnMOiRcKrzrV4wrE1w4Jc4oKFzrTEh3rDgeKChTPCqMOJauKCrMK@w683MzfDhsO8w63Ctz/RgsK54oCiN9Cyw6hK//8)

**Explanation:**

```python
“\n "-.\|“       "#  Push string '\n "-.\|'
•6ÅΩæÍ[ÕŽÇ4Δ¼µðв‹ìbÿ¹0mĆÛh6Ë\HvçÏ—ÜâE«εx±5Â\₅δćzÁ₅3¨Éj€¾ï737Æüí·?т¹•
                  # Compressed integer 18017524448214263331172789946872235969387180564028761120954323919616255702509406136041325094115009009004153150633415914465807454405990069100373808902652333314
 7в               # Converted to Base 7 as list:
                  # [1,1,1,1,4,3,2,2,3,4,0,1,4,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,0,6,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,0,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,1,2,3,4,0,6,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,0,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,0,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,6,0,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,6]
è                 # Index each item in this list in the string
 J                # Join the indexed characters together (and output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•6ÅΩæÍ[ÕŽÇ4Δ¼µðв‹ìbÿ¹0mĆÛh6Ë\HvçÏ—ÜâE«εx±5Â\₅δćzÁ₅3¨Éj€¾ï737Æüí·?т¹•` is `18017524448214263331172789946872235969387180564028761120954323919616255702509406136041325094115009009004153150633415914465807454405990069100373808902652333314`.

Huge thanks to [*@MagicOctopusUrn*'s ASCII art compress generator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120966/52210), after which <s>`žLR` has been golfed to `žh`, and the string has been fixed with the `…` and `«` because it contained a `"`</s> the transliterate has been golfed by reversing the string and number on the stack, using `в` instead of `B` to make it a list of characters instead, and index into it (thanks *@Emigna*).

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by using one string instead of two, using for example `“`. You can save another byte by indexing instead of transliterating.

Comment: @Emigna Ah, both are pretty smart, thanks! That second suggestion might probably golf some my previous ASCII-art answers as well. Will take a look later on at those once I have some time.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my previous comment that switching order of the string and number and using `в` was required for the indexing to save that third byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 91 bytes

```
/d/"-.//D/""--..//s/   //S/ss/s .-"d
 .-"Sd
|DSd
|SDsd
|DSD\\
|SDS|
|SSD|
 DSS|
S DS|
SS D|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYihDcAwDAR5prDCnV/CGzwNqZRKBWWm3t21S@7v3t/Ln9szcTB1AYY5VVeZQ0QAwh0uS@cZTZ4R1qD5r7Z3B6NIiyHGcko/rInMDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 139 bytes

```java
v->"    .-\"\"-.\n .-\"6\"-.\n|06\"-.\n|60   \"-.\n|060\\\n|606|\n|660|\n 066|\n 606|\n66 0|".replace("6","      ").replace("0","\"\"--..")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY6xbsMgEIZ3P8WJyUThxMSSNGO2TJG6lAzUsSMcjJEBS1GcZ3cxTtvp/@/jE3etGhVrr/dZd64fArRpxhi0wSbaKuje4mZXuPhtdAWVUd7DSWkLzwLgTX1QIcXY6yt06a08h0Hb29cF1HDzNKsAx/d3@8/kbVflAA18zCM7kMVAJokkDKXNVax94r9F8CT9QS5lZmJaQvAUwMUywQqFAD4RHGpnVFWXRJBtXgNA6D/liea1DJHQeZdvPT98qDvsY0CX7gzGlg0q58yjtNEYShftVbzmHw)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>169</strike> <strike>154</strike> 152 bytes

```cs
Console.Write("    .-\"\"-.\n .-\"2\"-.\n|12\"-.\n|21   \"-.\n|121\\\n|212|\n|221|\n 122|\n 212|\n 221|".Replace("1","\"\"--..").Replace("2","      "));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1BCwIhEIX/yjCnFVLQ656ic5c6dPEiJiGYxo4Fsbu/3dSlepf3zcfAs8Rtmlx5ko83OL8pu/sINhgi2MMMlE32Fl7JX@FofBwYzOWQIqXgxGXy2Q0INYJr1MiFjh3Vxov8gpL16Sel1t2ppZWStUCqdsEmoUkUJ/cIxtYJiTvsA1wIZH@vqoceZGws61o@)

*-15 bytes: Realized I could made use of C#'s Replace function and removed a variable.*
*-2 bytes: Left two unnecessary spaces in the Replace functions.*

---

Alternate way to do this using an anonymous function instead of writing directly to the console.

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>154</strike> 152 bytes

```cs
()=>{return("    .-\"\"-.\n .-\"2\"-.\n|12\"-.\n|21   \"-.\n|121\\\n|212|\n|221|\n 122|\n 212|\n 221|".Replace("1","\"\"--..").Replace("2","      "));};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY6xasMwEIb3PMXPTRLUAml1E2gK3bq0Q4eqg1CVIHDkoJMLxfGzu7JN23@57z7uuPPc@D6HeeCYznj95hIuLZK7BL46H/CAEb5zzDhW4uJK9Pjq4yeeXUyCS6577x9w@cwS4@5pSP5@swecsJ@F3B/GHMqQkyDUqMaSpUbZtKLZ@KZ/weg69Ce1taszt6UYXQu0WTpsEosk9RKuXf1XkKY7Wg80SpH896Z6rCEp26mdH/vEfRfUW44liJOodjdN0/wD)

*-2 bytes: Left two unnecessary spaces in the Replace functions.*

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 88 bytes

```
/%/   //$/"-.
//#/""--..//!/%%/% .-"$ .-"!$|#!$|!#%$|#!#\\
|!#!|
|!!#|
 #!!|
! #!|
!! #|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYghEsAwCAR9XsFBkOE@VFPRmYq6WP5Oibi9nd3fvd9nV9EpIuSkrhikUXWtCBJ0p0ssnQeYaT2YH7HrGu3IJiyHGNohp6Avq34)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 79 bytes

```
•6ÂËhHyã¡0÷íÓ].‚ηƶãqÛ-#Œ‘-)ìMι"ΩÒý³!7₄βýiÑ¡1:l*;∊ëžZ~ÙÂ¯Î©ïŒ×.gιü#‡•“. -"|
\“Åв
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AY8AcP9vc2FiaWX//@KAojbDgsOLaEh5w6PCoTDDt8Otw5NdLuKAms63xrbDo3HDmy0jxZLigJgtKcOsTc65Is6pw5LDvcKzITfigoTOssO9acORwqExOmwqO@KIisOrxb5afsOZw4LCr8OOwqnDr8WSw5cuZ865w7wj4oCh4oCi4oCcLiAtInwKXOKAnMOF0LL//w)

```
•...•“...“Åв  # trimmed program
          Åв  # characters in...
     “...“    # literal...
          Åв  # with indices in digits of...
•...•         # 17991054328044272488457460457310784314009191188977967735225363312688493035783656557746796791541044041617963464968803855853508169575617675885728820813516051270...
          Åв  # in base length of...
     “...“    # literal
              # implicit output
```